# Sorting order of Groups in kendo ui grid

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Here I have written stored procedure for getting CategoryName values based on id, Values are coming like India, America, Brazil up to service, But in UI section values are in automatically sorting in alphabetical order displaying groups like America, Brazil,India.  I wanted to show as in order display like India, America, Brazil format. What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: {
        type: "GET",
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: "some url placed here",
                dataType: "jsonp"
            }
        },
        pageSize: 20,
        serverSorting: false,
        group: {
            field: "CategoryName",
            aggregates: [{
                field: "abc",
                aggregate: "count"
            }, {
                field: "def",
                aggregate: "sum"
            }, {
                field: "ghi",
                aggregate: "sum"
            }]
        },
        aggregate: [{
            field: "abc",
            aggregate: "count"
        }, {
            field: "def",
            aggregate: "sum"
        }, {
            field: "ghi",
            aggregate: "sum"
        }]
    },
    columns: [
    //column section goes here.....
    ],
    sortable: false
    //...
});
```

});

Answer (score 1):

I remember somewhere in the kendo ui documentation (may be datasource > groups) it said that, if you define groups, the grouping requires the sorted data.. Remove all your groups and display the data in plain vanilla grid and see if some automatic sorting is applied.

Comment: Please improve your answer by quoting and linking the documentation.

Comment: Look here [Kendo UI Forum](http://www.telerik.com/forums/datasource-group-then-sort).  If you Group that overrides the Sort.  Currently they do not support Group and Sort.

Answer (score 0):

This is a complete guess, but have you tried setting the ServerSorting property to true?

Answer (score 0):

Kendo UI Grid Grouping gives you `ListSortDirection.Ascending` sorting by default.  If you want to do something else you have to set it.  If you are using the WebApi interface and generating a kendoRequest for the `Kendo.mvc.dll` method `.ToDataSourceResult(kendoRequest);` then you may try something like this:

```
var sort = kendoRequest.Sorts.FirstOrDefault();
var group = kendoRequest.Groups.FirstOrDefault(); 
if(sort != null && group != null) {
   if(sort.Member == group.Member && sort.SortDirection == ListSortDirection.Descending) {
      kendoRequest.Groups[0].SortDirection = sort.SortDirection;
   }
}
```

That way the Sort feature from the Grid affects the Group by column when they match.